# Setting Horizontal scroll bar on top of scroll pane

Tags: jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I am trying to set the scrollbar on JScrollPane. By default vertical scrollbar appear on right, and horizontal scrollbar appear on bottom of the content pane. I need to change the direction, i.e. vertical scrollbar on left, and horizontal scrollbar on top. I used the method

```
scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

that changes the vertical scrollbar appear on left, but unable to change the horizontal scrollbar to top. Can anyone help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the available orientations:

- java.awt.ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT
- java.awt.ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT
- java.awt.ComponentOrientation.UNKNOWN

it would seem that what you're trying to do isn't supported.

I would have to ask why you would want to do this anyway though? I would imagine that having a horizontal scrollbar at the top would have a detrimental effect on usability.

There may be a good reason why it's not supported.

Comment: I need show a ribbon like scroll pane for a touch screen monitor having inertia based scrolling, where scroll pane may appear at any side of the actual content display area.

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem here. Many applications that have inertia based scrolling (such as safari on the iPhone) use a horizontal scrollbar that appears at the bottom of the screen. Are you talking about a rotating display? If that's the case, you'd need to be rotating the view somehow. I'm not sure if this is any help but take a look at this question : [Tilting JComponents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271436/can-we-tilt-a-jpanel-at-an-angle)