# How can I rotate a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I am working on a chess game. I made my chess board using a `JPanel`.

This `JPanel` consists 64 `JLabel`s representing the `8x8` chess blocks.

I want to rotate this JPanel so that the entire chess board can be rotated according to the player's choice.

Please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: You forgot to mention what have you tried.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to do it. I know that an image inside the panel can be rotated but the entire JPanel cannot be rotated.

Answer (score 1):

JPanel is meant to be static, if you want a fancy rotation movement, you should load an imagemap and code an algorithm to rotate all pixels (or going openGL with joGL library if that were the case) or, if you don't want to show any dynamic translation, be sure that all the objects representing the pieces, the squares and the table itself, have a dimension attribute associated to them, so you can force a repaint of the jpanel with the dimension attributes of all your figures rewritten depending of the angular movement (i.e. a tower at (7,1) should appear now on (8,7) if the table is moved 90 grades counterclockwise).

This question is very general, but had in mind that all objects represented will have to own a dimension attribute so you can repaint them at different positions when JPanel is reloaded.

Comment: And when I say static, I mean JPanel won't manage dynamic movements by itself.

Comment: I do not want to show a fancy movement. Also, using the dimension attributes is a lot of work and is my last option. But is there any other easier option?

Comment: i'm sure you're using dimensions somehow to move the pieces. You need an algorithm to traslate your pieces if the table is rotated. In the case of a counterclockwise movement, pieces at the right will apperar now at the top, pieces at the left will appear now at the bottom, etc.

I don't think is a tough task. In fact, it looks almost trivial.

Comment: Hmm.. I was scared to mess with it coz the algorithms of my chess pieces also depend on these dimensional values. Anyways I will try to figure out a way to do it, without disturbing the algorithms for the pieces.

Comment: Of course they do. But the rotation is an event different from piece regular movements. You just have to be sure that when the rotation is done, the pieces' dimensions are modified before JPanel is reloaded. 

Going deeper, you'll have to take care than once the table is rotated, the permitted movements of the pieces will be modify as well their algorithms, so i.e. paws will move horizontal instead of vertical, etc. You can add a rotation parameter to your legalMovement methods to recalculate the way pieces can move.

Comment: There's no other way to do this if you're using static images. (In openGL you would simply rotate your camera ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rotate the image but not the panel.

Please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271588/1446006

Comment: Hmm.. That won't help in this situation. I want the entire panel to be rotated. Thanx anyways :)